# Retrofit: how to ensure second call waits for results from the first call

Tags: android, rest, android-asynctask, retrofit

I have an application where I do the login using a simple retrofit async call with Callback in the MyApplication.onCreate() method and store the userId that I get back as a global variable in MyApplication inside the retrofit callback.

Now on the first Activity onCreate method. I use the userId that I retrieved from the login APi call in a separate API call to retrieve some user specific data.

The problem is that in the Activity onCreate method when I want to call the second API call. the userId is still null since the first call in MyApplication didn't finish execution yet and the userId is not set yet.

How do I ensure that the second call is executed only after a userId is returned from the first call and set properly.

Please advice.

MyApplication class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

private String userId;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // login, password retrieved here.
    retrofitClient.login(login, password, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String userId, Response response) {
            setUserId(userId);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private Context context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = this;
    // do some logic.        
String userId = ((MyApplication) getApplication()).getUserId();
// NOW THE USERID is still NULL since the first call in the MyApplication      class is not done yet.
    retrofitClient.callSecondAPICall(userId, new Callback<ProductResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void success(MyResponse myResponse, Response response) {
    // do something.
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: buddy follow the @Gennadii Saprykin answer as it is the perfect solution.

Comment: use RxJava, and chain the calls. (Retrofit integrates very well with rx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it this way:

1. Create a listener interface with method `onUserIdLoaded(String id);`
2. Implement this interface in your `MainActivity`
3. Add a listener to `MyApplication` in your activity's `onResume()`: `((MyApplication) getApplication()).addListener(listener);`
   Remove this listener in `onPause()`:
   `((MyApplication) getApplication()).removeListener(listener);`
4. When the first request is finished, call `onUserIdLoaded(id)` method.
5. In your activity you check whether id is available or not. If it is available, you just use it for your second request. If it's not, you subscribe for `onUserIdLoaded(id)` event and start your second request only when this callback is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

On the first call onSuccess only make the second the call. Which mean you dont start your activity until the first call onSuccess is being called. With this you ensure that the first call is succeeded and userId is being saved.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make both calls in activity

**Way 1** :

Make First Call in activity and not inside your application class.
    on Success of First call make second call.

**Way 2**:
Use EventBus

1. Post Event of UserID call from Application Class
2. when you receive that event in activity initiate the second call.